# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline: Ignore backup files from Emacs and other editors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

In a Rails 3.1 project, if I edit `app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee` using Emacs, then Emacs creates a backup file named `app/assets/javascripts/users.js.coffee~` (note the trailing "~").

Unfortunately, the new Rails 3.1 asset pipeline sees this `.coffee~` file, and injects it directly into the generated `application.js`, which in turn causes JavaScript errors in the browser.

I *could* turn off backups in Emacs by writing:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist nil)
```

...or I could use:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.emacs-backups")))
```

...to move them into another directory.

But this would require every Emacs user on the project to reconfigure their Emacs, which is undesirable. I would prefer to configure Rails 3.1 to ignore files ending in `.coffee~`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Just to be clear: This is a Rail problem, not a Git problem?

Comment: @Wukerplank Yes. The new asset pipeline is picking up '*.coffee~' files, and injecting them unmodified into the generated 'application.js'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought this was a defect in the require_tree method; and it sort of is,
seems to be a few issues filed on this:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1863#issuecomment-1543809 (Rails)
https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/pull/119 (Sprockets)
https://github.com/sstephenson/hike/issues/9 (Hike, fix was made here)

looks like it was fixed recently, after Rails rc4 (hike-1.1.0), looks like hike-1.2.0 has been released with the fix, you could try updating your Gemfile to use the newer version

Comment: I'm using hike 1.2.1 (took the defaults with a fresh rails 3.1 gemset last week) and I'm still seeing this problem.

Comment: The regular expression is now excluding entries with the following match `/^\.|~$|^\#.*\#$/`